# rails respond_to format.js API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax

I am an experienced JAVA and C++ developer and I am trying to understand how rails works.

I got this code below:

```
respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to store_url }
        format.js { render :json => @line_item, :mime_type => Mime::Type.lookup('application/json'), 
                :callback => 'javascriptFunction' }
```

and I've been searching the api that defines what I can pass inside the `format.js {}` but I could not find..

first of all: what kind of statement is `format.js`, is that a variable?

and most important: what attributes can I pass into format.js {} ? can you pass the direct link? I've searched  over the http://api.rubyonrails.org/

Answer (score 118, accepted):

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js # actually means: if the client ask for js -> return file.js
end
```

`js` here specifies a mime-type that the controller method would send back as a response;
[Default Rails mime-types](http://apidock.com/rails/Mime).
If you try also with `format.yaml`:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
  format.yaml
end
```

that will mean that your controller will return `yml` or `js` depending on what the client-side is asking;

`{}` in terms of ruby is a [block](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/); 
If you don't specify any rails will try to render a default file from app/views/[contoller name]/[controller method name].[html/js/...]

```
# app/controllers/some_controller.rb
def hello
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

will look for `/app/views/some/hello.js.erb`; // at least in Rails v. 2.3.

If you do specify block:

```
respond_to do |format|
    # that will mean to send a javascript code to client-side;
    format.js { render             
        # raw javascript to be executed on client-side
        "alert('Hello Rails');", 
        # send HTTP response code on header
        :status => 404, # page not found
        # load /app/views/your-controller/different_action.js.erb
        :action => "different_action",
        # send json file with @line_item variable as json
        :json => @line_item,
        :file => filename,
        :text => "OK",
        # the :location option to set the HTTP Location header
        :location => path_to_controller_method_url(argument)
      }

  end
```

Comment: What if you want to specify the js file to be called, instead of the convention of same file name as method name? I am trying to use the same js file for different controllers.

Comment: `format.js { :render ...` should be `format.js { render ...`.  I'd edit it, but I have to change more than 6 characters to save the changes.

Comment: stil, the question remains: `what kind of statement is format.js, is that a variable?`

Comment: @Ferenjito, `format` is a variable from block `respond_to do |format|` , which holds an object. Calling `.js` on that object defines a behavior for javascript mimetype response. Sort of DSL

Comment: alone `format.js` throws me error > unknow format . but when i put `format.html` it allows me to go without entering in js.erb file . why

Answer (score 16):

I believe this was the url you were looking for:

https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to

This might also be helpful to some, to see that you can actually render js directly within the format.js method, if you for example only have a small one line js statement you want to return, and you **don't** want to defer to a RJS file like `controller_action_name.js.erb`:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to new_admin_session_path }
  format.js   { render :js => "window.location='#{ new_admin_session_path }'" }
end
```