# Rails 4 - Error Handling via Ajax - Error not firing

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to submit a "blank" form to purposely trigger an error.

However, it is still responding with the "Success" function and not flagging an error.  But, no records are being added.

The form works okay when I submit it with information in the input field.

**Form:**

```
 <%= simple_form_for :course, :url => {:action => 'create'}, :remote => true do |f| %>      
   <%= f.input :title %>
   <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
 <% end %>
```

**Model:**

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base 
  validates :title, presence: true
end
```

**Controller:**

```
 def create
   @course = Course.new(course_params)

   respond_to do |format|  
     if @course.save  
       format.html { redirect_to(:controller => 'schedule', :action => 'index') }  
       format.js  
     else  
       format.html { render :action => "new" }  
       format.js
     end  
   end  
 end
```

**create.js.erb**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form").on("ajax:success", function(e, data, status, xhr) {
   alert("Success!");
  }).bind("ajax:error", function(e, xhr, status, error) {
    alert("Error!");
  });
 });
```

**shared/error_messages.html.erb**

```
 <% if object && object.errors.size > 0 %>
   <div id="errorExplanation">
   <h2><%= pluralize(object.errors.size, "error") %> prohibited this record from being saved.</h2>
   <p>There were problems with the following fields:</p>
   <ul>
     <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
       <li><%= msg %></li>
     <% end %>
   </ul>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here?  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You dont need to have `document.ready` in your `js.erb` file. You could do something like this

controller

```
if @result = @course.save
 ..
```

create.js.erb

```
<% if @result %>
  alert("Success!");
<% else %>
  $('#error-div').html('<%= j(render :partial => 'shared/error_messages', :object => @course) %>');
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So, how would I then display the error on the form that rails raises?  E.g., "Title cannot be blank."

Comment: I have updated my answer. Here I am inserting the validation errors into a div with id error-div. You could do something similar.

Comment: Ah, I see!  Thank you.  So, if I wanted to display a partial view, how would I pass these errors to the partial? I updated my question above with my partial.

Answer (score 8):

Something you need to know:

---

**Errors**

Ajax errors only occur on *AJAX* errors (not Rails errors)

It took me a long time to figure this out -- just because your Rails method doesn't succeed, doesn't mean your Ajax call will trigger an error. Ajax will succeed because it's sent the data to the server

---

**Status**

To call the Ajax Error function, you could use the `status` argument to send an error header:

[rails respond_to format.js API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545148/rails-respond-to-format-js-api)

```
 respond_to do |format|  
     if @course.save  
       format.html { redirect_to(:controller => 'schedule', :action => 'index') }  
       format.js  
     else  
       format.html { render :action => "new" }  
       format.js   { render status: :500 }
     end
```

Comment: With the ajax response