# Ajax based cart is not working_Agile Web development with Rails 4.0

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

My server console output is as follows:

```
  Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 15ms

    ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template line_items/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
      * "/Users/MacBook/rails_projects/depot/app/views"):
    app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:47:in `create'
    Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/missing_template.erb within rescues/layout (0.7ms)
```

/app/controller/line_items_controller.rb as follows:

```
 def create
     product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
      @line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)

    respond_to do |format|                    ----> Line 47
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to(store_url) }
        format.js
        format.xml  { render :xml => @line_item,
          :status => :created, :location => @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @line_item.errors,
          :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
     end
    end
```

app/views/store/index.html.erb as follows:-

```
<% if notice %>
<p id='notice'><%= notice %></p>
<% end %>

    <h1>Your Pragamtic Catalogue </h1>

    <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <div class='entry'>
        <%= image_tag(product.image_url) %>
        <h3><%= product.title %></h3>
        <%= sanitize product.description %>
        <div class= "price_line">
            <span class="price"><%= number_to_currency(product.price) %></span>
            <%= button_to "Add to Cart", line_items_path(product_id: product), remote: true %>
        </div>
    </div>

<% end %>
```

When I add a book to the cart the browser does not do a thing but when I refresh the browser the book is added. Am I missing something?

respond_to do |format| of line_items_controller.rb is the Line 47 that is raising the error.

view/line_items/create.js.rjs file is as follow:

```
page.replace_html('cart', render(@cart))
```

Comment: which line is number 47?

Comment: BTW it seems like the code is executed and the save operation is successful, very likely the format responder for the js action is requiring a template. Can you share also the code that calls the action?

Comment: Have a look at the accepted answer for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545148/rails-respond-to-format-js-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the create.js.erb in line item view folder. Ajax will work with the response em js(format.js). Because the  action is create Rails will look for the same name as the action in a js file, in that case, create.js.erb. But remember, is the create.js.erb that does all the work to make the line item magically appear on the cart.

Here is my code from some time ago, same book.

[create.js.erb](https://github.com/cassioscabral/depot/blob/master/app/views/line_items/create.js.erb)

[create action on line_items_controller](https://github.com/cassioscabral/depot/blob/master/app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb#L29-L45)

Comment: You are right. I had to create the create.js.erb file to make it work. Thanks that helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As Cassio mentioned, I had to create the create.js.erb file in views/line_items and add the following code.

$('#cart').html("<%= escape_javascript render(@cart) %>");

Thanks.