# Ajax and Rails Completed 406 Not Acceptable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm completely lost as to how to make this request go through ajax without throwing back a 406 error. I am trying to add an item to a cart with ajax, and the item does get added and after a refresh the cart is updated. All I receive as an xhr notice with the 406 error. Any help is highly appreciated.

Product Controller

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

 def index
  @products = Shoppe::Product.root.ordered.includes(:product_categories, :variants)
  @products = @products.group_by(&:product_category)
 end

 def show
  @product = Shoppe::Product.root.find_by_permalink(params[:permalink])
 end

 def buy
  @product = Shoppe::Product.root.find_by_permalink!(params[:permalink]) || params[:variant] ? Shoppe::Product.root.find_by_permalink!(params[:permalink]).variants.find(params[:variant].to_i) : @product
  current_order.order_items.add_item(@product, 1)
   respond_to do |format|
    format.js
   end
 end

end
```

Show.html.erb

```
<h2><%= @product.name %></h2>

<% if @product.default_image %>
<%= image_tag @product.default_image.path, :width => '200px', :style => "float:right" %>
<% end %>

<p><%= @product.short_description %></p>
<p>
 <% if @product.has_variants? %> 
     <% @product.variants.each do |v| %>
         <%= form_tag product_path(@product.permalink, @product.permalink, :variant => v.id ),id: '#submit-form', remote: true do %>
         <%= submit_tag 'Add to basket', :disabled => !v.in_stock? %>
     <% end %>
   <% end %>
 <% else %>
  <b><%= number_to_currency @product.price %></b>
  <%= link_to "Add to basket", product_path(@product.permalink), :method => :post %>
 <% end %>
</p>

<hr>
 <%= simple_format @product.description %>
<hr>

<p><%= link_to "Back to list", root_path %></p>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
mount Shoppe::Engine => "/admin"



get "product/:permalink", to: "products#show", as: "product"
post "product/:permalink", to: "products#buy", as: "buy"
get "basket", to: "orders#show"
delete "basket", to: "orders#destroy"

root to: "products#index"

end
```

products.js.erb

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var data = $('#submit-form').attr('action')
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: data
    });
});
```

Comment: This is a little bit of a guess, as I don't have time to look into it in detail right now, but does adding `respond_to :json` at the top of the `ProductsController` fix your issue? If so, I'll post a more detailed answer in a few hours...

Comment: @TomLord : Unfortunately it does not, I keep getting the same 406 error, rails logs ActionController::UnknownFormat when trying to render app/controllers/products_controller.rb:15:in `buy'.

Comment: try to add a `dataType: 'script'` to your ajax call

Comment: @AlexandreAngelim : I just tried it and no luck :/

Comment: what about adding `format: 'js'` as well?

Comment: @AlexandreAngelim : No difference :(

Answer (score 1):

Looking up what `format.js` does, I found this: [rails respond_to format.js API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545148/rails-respond-to-format-js-api)

It seems `format.js` in your `buy` action will render the `buy.js` file. You haven't shown this file, so I'm figuring it doesn't exist.

I'm figuring what you're trying to do is render json, which is simple enough. You could replace:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
end
```

with this:

```
render json: <your object>.to_json
```

make sure to strip any private data before sending the response.

By the way, you should probably be attaching a callback to your `$.ajax` call.